# How to un-select some specific variables in a SAS sql process?

Tags: sql, sas

In SAS SQL process I always use the process like:

```
select v1, v2 ,v3....v10
from table_1;
```

However, if I want to select 99 variables out of 100 variables, it's not possible to write all of the variables in the "select" process.

I want to know if there are any better solutions to **un-select one or some specific variables** for the selection process?

I have tried to select all of the variables, then use the alter table process to drop the not wanted variables.

```
select*
from table_1;
alter table table_1
drop var50, var51;
```

It will be very helpful if anyone could me some suggestions. Thank you~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure that is possible in sas sql;

```
select * from table_1(drop=var50 var51);
```

but be warned variables are the dropped before read. So there is no access possible to them in statement so for example

```
select * from table_1(drop=var50 var51) where var50=1;
```

will not work. But when you use it for creating an new dataset you could rewrite it as:

```
create table_2(drop=var50 var51) as
select * from table_1 where var50=1;
```